# using nth-child() to represent a series

Tags: css, math, series

I am trying to use the nth-child selector for a grid which will repeat after every 6 occurrence. so the first and the 6th block will have same property and 2nd and 8th block will have same property. When I am doing the math I am starting from 6n and moving backwards I am doing 6n-1, 6n-2, 3n, 3n-1, n....so my series looks like

3n-2, 3n-1, 3n, 6n-2, 6n-1, 6n....is there a better way I can conclude this series? Also the 3n-2 and 6n position will always be same.My series works but I wonder if that is accurate

so the smallest repeat is

1= blue, 2= red, 3= purple, 4=orange, 5=pink, 6=blue

Comment: If it works, what is the question?

Comment: "is there a better way"

Comment: @Miro Since "is there a better way" depends, this question is too broad and/or primarily opinion-based - voted to close

Comment: Here is a good article how to use `nth-child`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/